# create PAM converstation

Tags: linux, c, pam

I tried to create a simple PAM module, that print some message, wait X second and return the PAM_SUCCESS status.

Firstly I tried with this script:

```
#include <security/pam_appl.h>
#include <security/pam_modules.h>
#include <security/pam_misc.h>
#include <security/pam_ext.h>
#include <unistd.h>

PAM_EXTERN int pam_sm_authenticate(pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags, int argc, const char **argv) {

    pam_info(pamh, "Test message" );
    
    sleep(3);

    return PAM_SUCCESS;
}

PAM_EXTERN int pam_sm_open_session(pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags, int argc, const char **argv) {
return PAM_SUCCESS;
}

PAM_EXTERN int pam_sm_close_session(pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags, int argc, const char **argv) {
return PAM_SUCCESS;
}

PAM_EXTERN int pam_sm_setcred( pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags, int argc, const char **argv ) {
    return PAM_SUCCESS;
}
```

But it's not the best, because it will be show my message after when the module is returned with the PAM_SUCCESS.

I think I should have to use the pam_conv, but I didn't find a simple example that works for me.

Comment: Is writing the module part of an exercise/homework or do you want to have an easy way to implement your "_print some message, wait X second and return the PAM_SUCCESS status_" requirement?

Comment: I would like to print some info during the auth, but I didn't find the right way. I tried to use the pam_conv (https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/libpam0g-dev/pam_conv.3.en.html), but I wasn't very successful with this. I would really appreciate for a working example

Comment: Not a helpful comment for your question, but I'd like to know if questions about coding `PAM` modules are really off-topic here (since I see this question it was voted to be closed). I'm thinking now that only `PAM` questions related to configurations (such as `/etc/pam.d/...`) are valid here.

Comment: @EdgarMagallon I think that is more than a valid question. But I think it would be wise to ask it on the meta site! (Also, where I'd draw the line would be whether a programming question is more Unix-specific or more generally asks how to learn how to use a library)

Comment: @MarcusMüller oh, thanks! That's useful. I will post that question on Meta tomorrow. (I saw nothing related to coding PAM modules on Meta, so it'd be helpful)